# validar contraseña con bcryptjs y passport

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bcryptjs

intento validar un contraseña con bcrypt y passport en node js pero siempre recibo undefined al imprimir la variable validPassword, aunque no esta terminado el código ya debería poder ver al menos 'true ' en mi console.log de la variable validPassport ,alguien sabe por que me da undefined?

```
const encryptPassword = async function (password){
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
};


const matchPassword = async function (password, savedPassword){
  await bcrypt.compare(password, savedPassword,function(err, matches) {
   if (err){
     console.log('Error while checking password')
   }else if (matches){
     console.log('The password matches!');
   }else{
     console.log('The password does NOT match!');
   }
 });
}

passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({
  usernameFild:'username',
  passwordFild:'password',
  passReqToCallback:true
  // this working
},async function(req,username,password,done) {
  const userFind = await userDB.find({username:username})
  if (userFind) {
    const validPassword = await matchPassword(toString(password),toString(userFind[0].password))
    console.log("validPassword==>", validPassword)
  }
```

se que la función aun no esta terminada pero aun así debería devolverme "true" sin embargo recibo un undefined cuando imprimo la variable "validPassword",por que pasa esto?

Comment: la función `matchPassword` no retorna nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función `matchPassword` no está retornando nada. Puedes devolver una promesa de la siguiente forma.

```
const matchPassword = function(password, savedPassword){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(password, savedPassword, (err, matches) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(matches)
    })
  })
}
```

Y la llamas de la misma forma que antes:

```
const validPassword = await matchPassword(toString(password),toString(userFind[0].password))
console.log("validPassword==>", validPassword)
```